# MBProgressHUD in UISplitViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a MBProgressHUD that is shown in the detailViewController of the UISplitViewApplication. It initially worked just fine when you start in either orientation. But once I change the orientation from landscape to portrait or vice versa, the view gets very messy. The code I did was:

```
 HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
```

This is defined in the viewDidLoad.
Has anyone successfully get around with this orientation issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by release-allocating the HUD when an orientation change. My issue is that the layout of the HUD in a split view controller is not correct. The black background and the indicator is separated when you switch views. So this is how I solve it.

Comment: New(er) versions of MBProgressHUD should work just fine in any orientation.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are using the latest version available (v0.4), then use the following:

```
// Should be initialized with the windows frame so the HUD disables all user input by covering the entire screen
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow

// Add HUD to screen
 [self.view.window addSubview:HUD];
```

Answer (score 1):

`MBProgressHUD` is just not made to change orientation when showing.

You can use my fork of [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/gcamp/SVProgressHUD) that will handle it just has you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Im having no problems with the MBProgressHUD when i change the orientation, this is how i use it.

```
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
    HUD.labelText = @"Please wait..";
    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"Getting data";
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(thefunction) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
```

Comment: that's the way I use it as well